# Error when compiling gdb on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, gdb, darwin

I am attempting to compile GDB 7.4 (the version that is on the gdb website) under Mac OSX and I receive the following error:

mach-o.c: In function 'bfd_mach_o_header_p':
mach-o.c.2978: warning: 'header.reserved' may be used uninitialized in this function

While trying to figure out the cause of this problem I came across the following article:

http://www.puredarwin.org/blockers

which claims that the cause of this problem is that the normal version of gdb doesn't work on the Darwin OS (when I do ./configure the "system type" comes up as i386-apple-darwin9.8.0). Is this corret, and if so, where do I get the "Apple version" which does work on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

GDB developers certainly *try* to make FSF version of GDB work on Mac OSX.

But since none of them actively use Mac OSX, breakage creeps in.

You should report the build problem [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

Also, adding `-Wno-error` to your CFLAGS should get you past that first hurdle (though there could be many more ahead).

Answer (score 0):

Apple puts a lot of custom junk in gdb (or did, they're probably not going to spend a lot of time on it, instead focusing on lldb). So out-of-the-box gdb doesn't work on osx.

You can grab their junky old version of gdb from http://opensource.apple.com/

Comment: bah, who wants the old junky version?

Comment: someone who wants to debug stuff on osx?

Comment: i got gdb 7.5.1 to compile using homebrew under ML but was running into the code sign error 0x5 problem, so I ended up running gdb 7.5.1 with sudo :-/  ...not the best solution

Comment: gdb is kinda 'old style' from what I gather. You should now look for lldb from the llvm package. Which _should_ be more closely related to the shipped XCode debugger since Apple has been directing a lot of effort to the llvm project and contributing. YMMV though, haven't tried it myself. But, lldm is the 'new hotness'.